# FFMPEG mp4 from http live streaming m3u8 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

How Can I extract mp4 from http live streaming m3u8 file? I Tried this command below:

```
ffmpeg -i {input file} -f rawvideo -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

I took this error:

> [NULL @ 0000000002f07060] Packet header is not contained in global extradata, corrupted stream or invalid MP4/AVCC bitstream Failed to open bitstream filter h264_mp4toannexb for stream 0 with codec copy: I

Comment: you can use this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hls-downloader/apomkbibleomoihlhhdbeghnfioffbej?hl=en

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Your command is not quite correct. The output format is not `rawvideo` and you don't need the bitstream filter `h264_mp4toannexb` which is used when you want to convert the `h264` contained in an `mp4` to the `Annex B` format used by `MPEG-TS` for example. What you want to use instead is the `aac_adtstoasc` for the `AAC` streams.

```
ffmpeg -i http://.../playlist.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Comment: Hello, This Answer helped me to record live stream from m3u8 url and video also gets saved in output.mp4. My question is can we specify time in seconds/minutes in this command so that the video saved is of the specified time. Currently it keeps on recording and stops until I press q in console. Thanks In advance

Comment: @Mayuri `-t <time>` after the input in s or hms.ms

Comment: hey can any one help me to get download progress fore the same case

Comment: with some m3u8 files that `ffmpeg` refuses to dump, it is still possible to do with vlc > open network > stream output: Settings > File.

Comment: It seems that the `http` part is required, `ffmpeg` doesn't do anything given an offline `.m3u8` file. Dunno why tho

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Check the console output, you probably need to enable `-protocol_whitelist file` to allow local M3U8 access.

Answer (score 26):

Aergistal's answer works, but I found that converting to mp4 can make some m3u8 videos broken. If you are stuck with this problem, try to convert them to **mkv**, and convert them to mp4 later.

Comment: I've found that `ffmpeg -i http://...m3u8 -c copy live.mkv` works very well. Just if anyone comes around and reads this.

Comment: @blackmiacool : How can do achieve this programatically ?

Comment: `.ts` also works quiet well for some streams

Comment: If you have a https:// address change it to http:// otherwise you get an "HTTP error 403 forbidden" error ... For converting MKV to MP4 simply use `ffmpeg -i file.mkv file.mp4` but why should one do that?

Comment: In case of local `m3u8` file, I also had to add a white-list at front, like: `ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i 02.m3u8 -c copy 02.mkv`

Comment: @ErichKuester - Because MKV is more resilient to potential corruption - I imagine?

Comment: @robert-perry - Maybe, don't know exactly, just meaning, if you can play MKV with vlc, there is no reason for extra-converting to MP4 ...

Comment: @rwenz3l I found your comment true also when input is a stream,    mkv could be played even if the stream is interupt or the ffmpeg process exit when pulling the video.   mp4 is not even playable in such situations

Comment: @ErichKuester But there's an "MP4" in the question.